# Define function J

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics

Define function $J : Q×Q → R$ by the rule $J(r, s) = r+√2s$ for all $(r, s) ∈ Q×Q.$
a) Is J one-to-one? Prove or give a counterexample.
b) Is J onto? Prove or give a counterexample

a)Suppose $(x1,y1)$ and $(y1,y2)$ are only elements of QXQ such that J(r1,s1) = (r2,s2). By definition of J, $(r1+√2s1) = (r2+√2s2)..$

I'm not sure i'm approaching this correct. Solution please.

Answer (score 1):

I think what you meant is suppose that $J(r_1, s_1) = J(r_2, s_2)$. This is the typical approach when trying to show that a function is injective. So in this case, we have
$$r_1 + s_1\sqrt{2} = r_2 + s_2\sqrt{2},$$
and so
$$r_1 - r_2 = (s_2 - s_1)\sqrt{2}.$$
What can you conclude now? As for onto, think about this: do there exist $r,s \in \mathbb{Q}$ such that $r + s\sqrt{2} = \pi$?

Comment: I'm not sure what to do after r1−r2=(s2−s1)√2.

Comment: $r_1,r_2,s_1,s_2$ are rational. So $r_1 - r_2$ is also rational. But $(s_2 - s_1)\sqrt{2}$ is irrational unless...

Comment: ...unless we divide by √2 ... then that would make it one-to one?

Comment: If you divide by $\sqrt{2}$, you have
$$\frac{r_1 - r_2}{\sqrt{2}} = s_2 - s_1.$$

Comment: Then i still don't get it then.

Comment: Here's a fact: If $p \neq 0$ is rational and $x$ is irrational, then $px$ is irrational.

Comment: yeah. but I don't see how this helpful.

Comment: There is no way to have $m = n\sqrt{2}$ where $m$ and $n$ are non-zero integers, because the left-hand side is rational and the right-hand side is irrational. Therefore, if you have an equation in that form, you know that $m$ and $n$ must be ...